# Clickonce deployment change update location after publish?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce, publish

My application has a different update location to publish location. I would like to change the update location after the application has been published using ClickOnce.  I have turned off signing before publish and I tried editing the manifest and other files to point to a different server for updates. When I tried to install the application I get signature errors.

I have been researching, there's supposedly a tool MageUI.Exe which will help create manifests however iam unable to find this tool.

I am running Windows 8, .Net Framework 4.5.2 and my sample application is a WPF Application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what VS version you're running but the below should give you an idea of what to do

Go to Project > "ProjectName" Properties > Publish > Updates

[image]

Now specify the update location. By default, it is the same as your Installation location but you can change it to something else.

[image]

Comment: I seem to be receiving an error stating "User has refused to grant required permissions".
Note that the updated location is an URL for a virtual folder in iis. I can install the application from here.

Comment: I have this exact setup. But when I go to launch application from start menu, where it installed in user folder. It does not check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to move your clickonce deployment so it is updated from a different URL than the original? [This blog article](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/how-to-move-a-clickonce-deployment/) shows how to do that.

MageUI.exe and mage.exe should be included with the Visual Studio installation. You can open a command prompt, navigate to c:\ and type "dsinit/s mageui.exe" and it will search the entire drive for it. If you don't have it, you can install the Windows SDK and it should have it. It's usually in c:\program files(x86)\Microsoft sdks\net...